# Building libcamera on MacOS Monterey

Tags: macos, raspberry-pi, meson-build

I'm trying to build libcamera on MacOS Monterey because it is a required dependency for [raspberrypi/libcamera-apps](https://github.com/raspberrypi/libcamera-apps).

`meson build` as described [here](https://libcamera.org/getting-started.html) is running into the error `src/libcamera/meson.build:68:0: ERROR: C shared or static library 'gnutls' not found`.

Trying to remediate the issue, I installed gnutls via homebrew. Since this didn't help I also tried to install gnutls-devel via MacPorts. This didn't help either.

Executing `pkg-config --list-all | grep gnutls` returns
`gnutls     GnuTLS - Transport Security Layer implementation for the GNU system`.

Does anyone know how to resolve that? I would also like to understand what is the preferred way of managing similar dependencies when developing for linux under MacOS.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the above issue I have figured out the location on gnutls on my MacBook. As next step, I set the environment variable `LIBRARY_PATH` to this location by executing `export LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/local/lib`.